# Which one is better ? URLReWriter.net or URLReWriting.NET

Tags: .net, urlrewriter.net, urlrewriting.net

I don't know whether you've been come across [urlrewriter.net](http://urlrewriter.net) because as I've seen so far [urlrewriting.net](http://urlrewriting.net) is kinda more popular.

Could someone please tell me which one is actually easier to implement and more powerful?

Thanks...

Comment: God, why did you guys vote down this topic now ?

Comment: Seems a fair enough question to me...

Comment: @JonoW Thanks :) These days people are weird, they are just voting down whatever they see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your answers tho.

I've found UrlReWriter.net more useful and easier to implement to current projects and also the other one whatever I did it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm glad you found your answer on this and that UrlRewriter.net is working for you.  My two cents would be the opposite. Here is my blog post on it. http://dotnetblogger.com/post/2009/03/19/URL-Rewriting-Made-Easy.aspx

Answer (score 0):

URLRewriter.net is much much better than urlrewriting.net

Answer (score 0):

I tried both 2 years ago and I settled with using URLRewriter. I cannot remember why I did :/ .. in IIS 7 you have that built in but I've encountered some problems with postbacks & the  append query string flag... 
ScottGu got a good post about URLRewriting in general that you can check out if you haven't already.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx